# avoid superimposition of div in position:asbolute

Tags: css

I have many div, which are in `position:absolute`.
I try to avoid their superimposition only with CSS rule. I don't want to change the top value.

```css
.try {
  /*some magic?*/
}
#pos1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 30px;
}
#pos2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 90px;
  left: 30px;
}
#pos3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 30px;
}
#pos4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 400px;
  left: 30px;
}
#current {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50px;
}
#expected {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="current">Current</h1>

<div id="pos1" class="try"></div>
<div id="pos2" class="try"></div>

<h1 id="expected">Expected</h1>

<div id="pos3"></div>
<div id="pos4"></div>
```

Here is also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0azbx976/5/) :

ps: I supose this behavior it's stupid because I ask for position absolute.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a very inflexible layout method...there any many other which are more flexible [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow of the document. That means surrounding content ignore them and occupy their place:

> [**9.6 Absolute positioning**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning)
>
> In the absolute positioning model, a box [...] is removed from the
>   normal flow entirely (it has no impact on later siblings). [...] The
>   contents of an absolutely positioned element [...] may obscure the
>   contents of another box (or be obscured themselves), depending on the
>   stack levels of the overlapping boxes.

So either don't use absolutely positioning, or move your elements (e.g. with margins).